# Downloading software from internet

Tags: command-line, internet, downloads, debian

I need to download a file from [this site](http://krpano.com/download/).

I saved the file elements as `Linux 64.bit` into a temp folder in my desktop.

How do I get these files from my temp desktop folder to its final destination so I can use this new software I just purchased?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Could you tell us from which website you downloaded the software? Which software is it?

Comment: The file format would be helpful too. most software has a deb package, which is really easy to install under debian.

Comment: Which file did you download?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one file there listed as Linux 64-bit, so I assume that's what you downloaded. That's a .tar.gz file. Move or copy the file to its own folder. To unzip it, browse to that folder in a terminal, then:

```
tar -zxvf kprano*.tar.gz
```

For this particular file there's nothing else to be done since it contains binary programs ready to run. `ls` will list the files. Run them with `./<filename>`

The zip file above it is similar, containing demo html apps ready to run. Once it's in the folder you want, unzip it with `unzip kprano*.zip`